# ERROR TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'date.toISOString')

Tags: javascript, react-native

While working on a React Native project ,I encountered the following error:

`TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'date.toISOString')`

As I am practicing as a newbie with 'academind' course, my code is quite similar to his code on github. Please refer to the link below:
[https://github.com/academind/react-native-practical-guide-code/tree/09-user-input/code/09-adding-error-styling](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

His code(academind) is working fine but it's not working for me. Please check my code with his code (on github).

```
 ERROR  TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'date.toISOString')

This error is located at:
    in ExpenseItem (created by CellRenderer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by CellRenderer)
    in VirtualizedListCellContextProvider (created by CellRenderer)
    in CellRenderer (created by VirtualizedList)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by ScrollView)
    in RCTScrollView (created by ScrollView)
    in ScrollView (created by ScrollView)
    in ScrollView (created by VirtualizedList)
    in VirtualizedListContextProvider (created by VirtualizedList)
    in VirtualizedList (created by FlatList)
    in FlatList (created by ExpensesList)
    in ExpensesList (created by ExpensesOutput)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by ExpensesOutput)
    in ExpensesOutput (created by AllExpenses)
    in AllExpenses (created by SceneView)
    in StaticContainer
    in EnsureSingleNavigator (created by SceneView)
    in SceneView (created by BottomTabView)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by Screen)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by Background)
    in Background (created by Screen)
    in Screen (created by BottomTabView)
    in RNSScreen (created by AnimatedComponent)
    in AnimatedComponent
    in AnimatedComponentWrapper (created by InnerScreen)
    in Suspender (created by Freeze)
    in Suspense (created by Freeze)
    in Freeze (created by DelayedFreeze)
    in DelayedFreeze (created by InnerScreen)
    in InnerScreen (created by Screen)
    in Screen (created by MaybeScreen)
    in MaybeScreen (created by BottomTabView)
    in RNSScreenContainer (created by ScreenContainer)
    in ScreenContainer (created by MaybeScreenContainer)
    in MaybeScreenContainer (created by BottomTabView)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by SafeAreaInsetsContext)
    in SafeAreaProviderCompat (created by BottomTabView)
    in BottomTabView (created by BottomTabNavigator)
    in PreventRemoveProvider (created by NavigationContent)
    in NavigationContent
    in Unknown (created by BottomTabNavigator)
    in BottomTabNavigator (created by ExpensesOverview)
    in ExpensesOverview (created by SceneView)
    in StaticContainer
    in EnsureSingleNavigator (created by SceneView)
    in SceneView (created by SceneView)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by DebugContainer)
    in DebugContainer (created by MaybeNestedStack)
    in MaybeNestedStack (created by SceneView)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by SceneView)
    in RNSScreen (created by AnimatedComponent)
    in AnimatedComponent
    in AnimatedComponentWrapper (created by InnerScreen)
    in Suspender (created by Freeze)
    in Suspense (created by Freeze)
    in Freeze (created by DelayedFreeze)
    in DelayedFreeze (created by InnerScreen)
    in InnerScreen (created by Screen)
    in Screen (created by SceneView)
    in SceneView (created by NativeStackViewInner)
    in Suspender (created by Freeze)
    in Suspense (created by Freeze)
    in Freeze (created by DelayedFreeze)
    in DelayedFreeze (created by ScreenStack)
    in RNSScreenStack (created by ScreenStack)
    in ScreenStack (created by NativeStackViewInner)
    in NativeStackViewInner (created by NativeStackView)
    in RNCSafeAreaProvider (created by SafeAreaProvider)
    in SafeAreaProvider (created by SafeAreaInsetsContext)
    in SafeAreaProviderCompat (created by NativeStackView)
    in NativeStackView (created by NativeStackNavigator)
    in PreventRemoveProvider (created by NavigationContent)
    in NavigationContent
    in Unknown (created by NativeStackNavigator)
    in NativeStackNavigator (created by App)
    in EnsureSingleNavigator
    in BaseNavigationContainer
    in ThemeProvider
    in NavigationContainerInner (created by App)
    in ExpensesContextProvider (created by App)
    in App (created by withDevTools(App))
    in withDevTools(App)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in AppContainer
    in main(RootComponent)
```

## ExpenseItem.js

```
import { Pressable, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { getFormattedDate } from '../../util/date';

function ExpenseItem({ id, description, amount, date }) {
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  function expensePressHandler() {
    navigation.navigate('ManageExpense', {
      expenseId: id
    });
  }

  return (
    <Pressable
      onPress={expensePressHandler}
      style={({ pressed }) => pressed && styles.pressed}
    >
      <View style={styles.expenseItem}>
        <View>
          <Text style={[styles.textBase, styles.description]}>
            {description}
          </Text>
          <Text style={styles.textBase}>{getFormattedDate(date)}</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.amountContainer}>
          <Text style={styles.amount}>{amount.toFixed(2)}</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    </Pressable>
  );
}
```

## Date.js

```
export function getFormattedDate(date){
    return date.toISOString().slice(0, 10);
}

export function getDateMinusDays(date,days){
    return new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() - days);
    //we can get a date, number of days in the past.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is simply an undefined error.

You can safe check on `getFormattedDate` function like:

```
export function getFormattedDate(date){
    if(date)
       return date.toISOString().slice(0, 10);
    else 
       return null;
}
```

However, main problem is date is coming undefined. So you should check the date value where you use the `ExpenseItem` component.

```
<ExpenseItem 
  id={id}
  description="hello"
  amount={3}
  date={date} // this should not be undefined
```

Debug your code :)

Have fun!